# Image Displaying On Mouse Problem Pygame How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/46ce5c66bd433d4d0829f03cabda2163) what I am trying to do is when my mouse clicks that button and my score is 1 then it should draw the image on the mouse but its only drawing when the mouse clicks on the button even though I added an else statement else if we arent on the button the image should still be on our mouse even if we are not over the button position

what I tried first I said if my score >= 1 then if we go and click our button  it should draw our Tower_image but I want it so even if we hover over another place the image is still shown but its only showing when its on the button and clicked

```
# our tower mouse image
Tower_image = pygame.image.load('tower1.png').convert_alpha()

pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
tower_pos_list = []      
    
# our main loop
cashtimer = 0
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False



        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if greenbutton1.isOver(pos):
                shop1.y = 500
                
            if exit2.isOver(pos):
                shop1.y = 9100


            if score >= 1:
                if drawtower1.isOver(pos): 
                    tower_pos_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

            # [...]

            for pos in tower_pos_list:
                window.blit(Tower_image, Tower_image.get_rect(center = pos))
```

MY FULL CODE:

```
import pygame,random
pygame.init()

# our game window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),pygame.NOFRAME)
pygame.display.set_caption("Tower Defense Game")






class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.over = False

    def draw(self,window,outline=None):
                #Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, outline, (self.x-2,self.y-2,self.width+4,self.height+4),0)
                    
        pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),0)
                
        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (255,255,255))
            window.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width/2 - text.get_width()/2), self.y + (self.height/2 - text.get_height()/2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
                #Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True
                    
        return False

    def playSoundIfMouseIsOver(self, pos, sound):
        if self.isOver(pos):            
            if not self.over:
                click.play()
                self.over = True
        else:
            self.over = False




colors = (155,255,255)
greenbutton1 = button((colors),680,15,90,60, '')
exit2 = button((colors),680,95,90,60, '')
drawtower1 = button((colors),120,553,60,20, '')

buttons = [greenbutton1,exit2,drawtower1]




# the buttons for the shop MENUUUU
class move:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


black = (39, 174, 96)      
white = (250,250,250)
check1 = move(20,-590,50,940,white)

check2 = move(20,370,240,40,white)

check3 = move(270,230,50,160,white)

check4 = move(270,170,310,50,white)

check5 = move(580,170,50,170,white)

check6 = move(570,370,80,50,white)

void = move(-4,-470,90,500,black)

towerhit1 = move(660,350,80,80,white)

moves = [check1,check2,check3,check4,check5,check6]


# our fps
fps = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



class bg:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 2
        self.image = pygame.image.load("map.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.image,self.rect)

white = (255,255,255)
bg1 = bg(0,0,0,0,white)



class shop:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.image = pygame.image.load("shop.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.image,self.rect)

shop1 = shop(0,9100,50,0,white)



# my tower health
class tower:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color  = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y + 30, 46,60)
        self.health = 10
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 32, self.y + 30, 46,60)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (24, 106, 59), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 90, 255 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 46))

        
tower1 = tower(500,505,50,50,white)

class money:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.font = pygame.font.Font("times.ttf", 40)
        self.cash = 0
        self.cashtext = self.font.render("" + str(self.cash), True, (88, 214, 141))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.cashtext,self.rect)


money1 = money(380,24,50,50,white)



class towertext:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.font = pygame.font.Font("times.ttf", 50)
        self.health_text = 100
        self.cashtext = self.font.render(str(self.health_text)  + "%" ,  True, (88, 214, 141))
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.cashtext,self.rect)


towertext1 = towertext(590,444,50,50,white)









# our monster class
class monster:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.walk = [pygame.image.load("monsta1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("monsta2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("monsta3.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("monsta4.png")]

        self.hit = [pygame.image.load("mhit1.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("mhit2.png")]
        self.next_frame_time = 0
        self.fps = 60
        self.speed = 3
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.direction = "hit"
        self.direction = "walk"
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.health = 10
        self.hitbox = (self.x + -18, self.y, 46,60)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
         

            
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "walk":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            image_list = self.walk


        elif self.direction == "hit":
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            image_list = self.hit
            
                

                # Is it time to show the next animation frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_frame_time ):
                    # set the time for the next animation-frame
            inter_frame_delay = 2990 // self.fps   
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_frame_delay  # in the future
                    # move the current image to the next (with wrap-around)
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len( image_list ):
                self.anim_index = 0
                            
        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y + 30, 46,60)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (23, 32, 42), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 40, 40, 10)) # NEW
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (169, 50, 38), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 40, 40 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 0
        player_rect.centery += -20
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)




monsters = []
level = [" m                                                                     ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         " m                                                                     ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         " m                                                                     ","                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         " m                                                                     ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         " m                                                                     ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
         " m                                                                     ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",

         " m                                                                     ",
         "                                                                      ",
         "                                                                      ",
  
         ]


for iy, row in enumerate(level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "m":
            new_platforms = monster(ix*9.8, iy*-16, 50,50,(255,255,255))
            monsters.append(new_platforms)



# scores


# auto cash timer

        



class Partic:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.partilight = pygame.image.load("tower1.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.partilight,self.rect)

# our invisible score
font = pygame.font.Font("times.ttf", 60)
score = 0
scoretext = font.render("Enemys ?/" + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
scorerect = scoretext.get_rect()
scorerect.center = ((620,150))


particles = []
visible = False
def redraw():

    for move in moves:
        move.draw()

    towerhit1.draw()       
    window.fill((35, 155, 86))



    
    bg1.draw()
    
    for monster in monsters:
        monster.draw()



    money1.draw()

    shop1.draw()


    # DRAW OUR VOID
    #    to hide our enemys:
    void.draw()

    
    tower1.draw()

    # my tower health
    towertext1.draw()
    

    
    for button in buttons:
        button.draw(window)

    for partic in particles:
        partic.draw(window)









def keyevents():
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        bg1.x -= bg1.speed

        # OUR MONSTER
        for monster in monsters:
            monster.x -= bg1.speed

        # OUR INVISIBLE MOVING RECT 
        for move in moves:
            move.x -= bg1.speed

        # our money rect
        money1.x -= bg1.speed

        # OUR BUTTONS
        for button in buttons:
            button.x -= bg1.speed

        # our shop stop it from scrolling
        shop1.x -= bg1.speed

        # my tower health
        towertext1.x -= bg1.speed
        
        # my tower actual health bar
        tower1.x -= bg1.speed

        # our void TO HIDE OUR ENEMYAS
        void.x -= bg1.speed
        
            
        
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        bg1.x += bg1.speed
        for monster in monsters:
            monster.x += bg1.speed
            
        for move in moves:
            move.x += bg1.speed

        money1.x += bg1.speed

        # OUR BUTTONS
        for button in buttons:
            button.x += bg1.speed

        # our shop stop it from scrolling
        shop1.x += bg1.speed


        # my tower health
        towertext1.x += bg1.speed
        # my tower actual health bar
        tower1.x += bg1.speed


        # our void TO HIDE OUR ENEMYAS
        void.x += bg1.speed        
            
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bg1.y += bg1.speed
        for monster in monsters:
            monster.y += bg1.speed

        for move in moves:
            move.y += bg1.speed

        money1.y += bg1.speed

        # OUR BUTTONS
        for button in buttons:
            button.y += bg1.speed

        # our shop stop it from scrolling
        shop1.y += bg1.speed
        
        # my tower health
        towertext1.y += bg1.speed
        # my tower actual health bar
        tower1.y += bg1.speed            


        # our void TO HIDE OUR ENEMYAS
        void.y += bg1.speed
            

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        bg1.y -= bg1.speed
        for monster in monsters:
            monster.y -= bg1.speed

        for move in moves:
            move.y -= bg1.speed

        money1.y -= bg1.speed
        
        # OUR BUTTONS
        for button in buttons:
            button.y -= bg1.speed

        # our shop stop it from scrolling
        shop1.y -= bg1.speed

        # my tower health
        towertext1.y -= bg1.speed

        # my tower actual health bar
        tower1.y -= bg1.speed


        # our void TO HIDE OUR ENEMYAS
        void.y -= bg1.speed        
        

def checkpoints():
    if check1.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):
        monster.y += 0.4

            
    if check2.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):
        monster.x += 0.4

    if check3.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):
        monster.y -= 0.4

    if check4.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):
        monster.x += 0.4

    if check5.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):
        monster.y += 0.4

    if check6.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):
        monster.x += 0.4



    # what happens if our monster hits our tower?
    if towerhit1.rect.colliderect(monster.rect):        
        if tower1.health > -42:
            tower1.health -= 1
            towertext1.health_text -= 2
            towertext1.cashtext = towertext1.font.render(str(towertext1.health_text)  + "%" ,  True, (88, 214, 141))
            monster.x = 20
            monster.y = -100



# our tower mouse image
Tower_image = pygame.image.load('tower1.png').convert_alpha()

pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


tower_pos_list = []      
    
# our main loop
cashtimer = 0
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            if greenbutton1.isOver(pos):
                shop1.y = 500
                
            if exit2.isOver(pos):
                shop1.y = 9100


            if score >= 10:
                if drawtower1.isOver(pos): 
                    tower_pos_list.append(pygame.mouse.get_pos())




                          # [...]

        for pos in tower_pos_list:
            window.blit(Tower_image, Tower_image.get_rect(center = pos))


 
    # WHAT HAPPENS  if we have 10$ cash and we click or drawbutton1?
    if money1.cash >= 10:
        score += 1                
        scoretext = font.render("Enemys ?/" + str(score), True, (255,255,255))
        scorerect.center = ((620,150))
    
    for monster in monsters:
        monster.drection = "walk"
        checkpoints()

   


    # this will give use cash every 50 secondes

    cashtimer += 1
    if cashtimer >= 60:
        money1.cash += 12
        money1.cashtext = money1.font.render("" + str(money1.cash), True, (88, 214, 141))
        cashtimer = 0





  


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    keyevents()




    redraw()
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: when you click button then you should only add image (and position) to some list.  And later use this list in every loop to draw all images - without checking any `score` or other variable and without checking mouse click. Everything what is on this list has to be drawn in every loop.

Comment: Could you give me like an example I am working on a shop menu I need the score and the button fir example if my player has 10 coins and he clicks the button then it should draw thst inage on the mouse even though I am not clicking anymore the image still shows

Comment: In your code you use `pos` and `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`. Is this correct?

Comment: yes thats what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a state `place_tower`. Set the state `True` when you click the button. Draw the tower at the current mouse position if the status `place_tower` is `True`:

```py
place_tower = False

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = event.pos

            if greenbutton1.isOver(pos):
                shop1.y = 500
                
            if exit2.isOver(pos):
                shop1.y = 9100
    
            if score >= 1:
                if drawtower1.isOver(pos): 
                    place_tower = True

    # [...]

    if place_tower:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        window.blit(Tower_image, Tower_image.get_rect(center = pos))
```

---

If you want to place the tower where it is clicked, you need to add a list that will store the final position of the towers:

```py
place_tower = False
towers = []

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = event.pos

            if place_tower:
                place_tower = False
                towers.append(pos)

            else:
                if greenbutton1.isOver(pos):
                    shop1.y = 500     
                if exit2.isOver(pos):
                    shop1.y = 9100
                if score >= 1:
                    if drawtower1.isOver(pos): 
                        place_tower = True

    # [...]

    if place_tower:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        window.blit(Tower_image, Tower_image.get_rect(center = pos))
    for pos in towers:
        window.blit(Tower_image, Tower_image.get_rect(center = pos))
```

Comment: I tried your method and the button when I click it nothing pops up at all*I have updated the post* [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/6bf68ac10808a8099add1b07f5756175)

Comment: @HabibIsmail See the answer and respect the indentation.

Comment: I am not sure why its the same again the indention is good the image doesnt show at all when I click on the button I checked if its blitting over another image and its not

Comment: @HabibIsmail I didn't just change the indentation, but I changed the complete answer. Note `score >= 1`

Comment: OOH NVVM I fixed it!!